# GDAL 3.1.0 on Windows 10 machine

Tags: gdal

I need help installing GDAL 3.1.0 on my Windows 10 computer.  I was pointed to download from here, http://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1911-x64-gdal-mapserver.zip .  I have unzipped and run sdkshell.bat and it takes me to a cmd window, my question is what comes next and how do I install it?

Comment: I have also looked at the documentation at the documentation link below, any ideas. http://download.gisinternals.com/documents/gisinternals_tools_and_resources.pdf

Comment: Any ideas on how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you still need it and haven't found the answer. sdkshell.bat create environment variable for gdal, so make sure you extract it in the folder you want it to be installed. After you run it, you can use gdal on cmd or powershell.

Comment: I tried this and I kept on running into issues with running python files on gdal, e.g. gdal2tiles.py. I've made a stack post and a different github issue, but not getting much help. DO you know why? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/365216/how-to-installing-gdal-on-windows-10-using-binaries-for-command-line-functional?noredirect=1#comment597666_365216

Comment: Also, @Sahit or Bee Zee, did you need to keep gdal 3.0 core in order to run them? I believe so but please confirm.